# Parcel character encoding

Tags: javascript, html, bundle, parceljs

In **Parcel 2 RC** we use **ES modules**, so we need to add the type="module" attribute to the script tags (Otherwise, we get an error message). When we chose a script tag to be a module the code is treated as a JavaScript module, and the processing of the script content is not affected by the **charset**. My question is:
How to specify, to the module, the encoding ("**utf-8"**) so that we can use special characters?

```
 <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mozilla docs, the charset field of the `<script>` tag is deprecated:

> If present, its value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for "utf-8". It’s unnecessary to specify the charset attribute, because documents must use UTF-8, and the script element inherits its character encoding from the document.

So I think you can just use special characters in your `.js` files by default, and parcel will respect them.

See [this example in the parcel repl](https://parcel-repl.vercel.app/#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)